# MapHttpRoute for specified controller

Tags: web-services, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I created a WebApi 2 web service.
To support routing more complex than the default one for some endpoints, I add something like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "StatusApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Status/{status}",
    defaults: new { status = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DisplayUnitApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/DisplayUnit/{unit}",
    defaults: new { status = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I meant these new routes not for all the endpoints, but only for some of them.
*Unfortunately* now all the endpoints support these routing, but I prefer to keep the *new* routing only for my chosen endpoints.

Is it possible to be *selective*?

An example:

> POST api/DoAction
>
> POST api/DoAction/Status
>
> POST api/DoAction/Name/{unit}

Before adding the new routes, the only available was POST api/DoAction. For this controller, I'd like to keep only the original endpoint reachable.

Thanks,
Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Web API 2 you have attibute routing:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Therefore you route maps to the general default routes and the and the specific actions attibute them to what you desire:

```
[httpPost, Route("api/DoAction")]

[httpPost, Route("api/DoAction/Status]

[httpPost, Route("api/DoAction/Name/{unit}]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try below code**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "StatusApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Status/{status}",
defaults: new { controller = "xxxx", action = "yyyyy" });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DisplayUnitApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/DisplayUnit/{unit}",
defaults: new { controller = "xxx", action = "yyyyy" });
```